# Series proof for $e^x$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, exponential-function

Problem:
Prove $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n=e^x$$
I am a bit confused on how I should start this proof. Any pointers on how I should start would help.

Comment: Define $e^x$. ${}{}$

Comment: We aren't allowed to use the taylor series. I am also confused what you mean by define e^x. Would I have to set e^x=f(x)  ?

Comment: give us the definition of $e^x$ you're using

Comment: e is the constant that is the base of the natural logarithm

Comment: So how have you defined the natural logarithm and its base, then? To many people, what you've posted is the usual *definition* of the symbol $e^x$, and the properties of the function are derived from it.

Comment: oh would e^x = lim n to infinity (1+x/n)^n?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433442/why-is-sum-n-0-infty-fracxnn-ex

Answer (score 2):

Use any definition of the exponential function you want, then prove that it is equivalent to that infinite sum. 
Example: $$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^n,$$ we just have to prove the following: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
You can find out the proof of the equivalence of definitions of $e^x$ in this  [article](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Exponential_Function).

Comment: Is there anything I could say about $$\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n}{e^x}$$?

Comment: @user111392 Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$, that would equal $1$.