# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\lambda^y}{y!}$ to $e^\lambda$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

How can I show that

$$ \sum_{y=0}^\infty \frac{λ^y}{y!} = e^λ $$?

I only get so far as to show that the series will converge (by ratio test), but not further, I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: Have you tried taking derivatives with respect to $\lambda$?

Comment: Consider what happens when $y\ge 2\lambda$.

Comment: Do you know about Taylor series?  In probability, this is used for Poisson distributions ($\lambda > 0$)..  $P(X = k) = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k/k!$, for $k = 0, 1,\dots .$ Your equation endures that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k) = 1.$

Comment: Which definition of $e^\lambda$ are you using?

Comment: Some older related posts: [Series proof for $e^x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792332/series-proof-for-ex) and [Why is $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433442/why-is-sum-n-0-infty-fracxnn-ex)

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing which definition of $e^{\lambda}$ you are assuming. For many people (like me) that series *is* the definition of $e^\lambda$, so there is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is one of the possible definitions of the exponential functions in the real field. There are really many possible definitions. I resume here the most known:

1) as a limit:
$$
e^x=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n  
$$
2) as the solution of differential function: $e^x = f(x)$ such that:
$$ 
f'(x)=f(x)\qquad \mbox{ with the initial condition } \qquad f(0)=1
$$
3) as the solution $e^x=f(x)$ of the functional equation:
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\qquad \mbox{ with the condition } \qquad f'(0)=1
$$
4) as a series as in your question:
$$
e^x= 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^k}{k!}
$$
5) as a continued fraction$$
e^x=\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{x}{1+x-\cfrac{x}{2+x-\cfrac{2x}{3+x-\cfrac{3x}{4+x-\ddots}}}}}
$$
And we can show that all these definitions are equivalent ( in $\mathbb{R}$).

As an example, using teh binomial formula, we have:

$$
\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n  =1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{x^k}{n^k}
$$
and the coefficient of the $k-$power is:
$$
\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!\,n^k}=\dfrac {1}{k!} \, \dfrac{1\times 2 \times 3 \cdots \times n}{[1\times 2  \cdots \times (n-k)]\,\times \,\underbrace {n\times n \cdots \times n}_{k \,\mbox{times}}}
$$ 
that, simplifyng and reordering becomes:

$$
\begin{split}
\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!\,n^k}&= \dfrac {1}{k!} \,\dfrac{\overbrace{(n-k+1)\times(n-k+ 2) \cdots \times (n-1)}^{(k-1)\,\mbox{factors}}}{\underbrace {n\times n \cdots \times n}_{(k-1) \,\mbox{factors}}} \\
&=\dfrac {1}{k!}\,\left(1-\dfrac{k-1}{n}\right)\,\left(1-\dfrac{k-2}{n}\right)\cdots\,\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right) 
\end{split}
$$

and taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ we have:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!n^k}=\dfrac{1}{k!}
$$
so that:
$$
\exp(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^k}{k!}
$$

If you want link the definitions 2) and 4), than derive term by term the series, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: A limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{k,n} = a_k$ does not imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k,n} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$ in general.  Some sort of uniformity/dominated convergence argument must be made.