# Find the limit of $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{6^k}{k!}$ if it exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am calculating the below infinite series sum but I haven't figured out how to start. Could anyone give me a hint to solve this?

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{6^k}{k!} =  \frac{6^1}{1!} + \frac{6^2}{2!} + \frac{6^3}{3!} + ...  $$

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Look at series expansion of e^x.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433442/why-is-sum-n-0-infty-fracxnn-ex) and plug in $x=6$

Comment: OMG, I forgot the series expansion for e^x!!! Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's difficult to give a hint without completely answering this, but here it is. A strong **hint**:

$$e^x = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} = 1 +\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} $$

Comment: Thanks so much!! I completely forgot the series expansion for $e^x$.

Comment: @Sophil You're welcome. So did you figure out what the final answer is?

Comment: Yes :) I am about to accept your answer but it seems that MSE doesn't allow to accept the answer within 5 minutes after posting.

Comment: @Sophil Oh, sure, there's no need to hurry accepting; that's not why I asked. I just wanted to make sure you understood the hint and got to the correct answer.

Comment: Yes I know :) You are so considerate!! Thank you so much for your help! It was a very strong hint! :)

Comment: (+1) for the words “It's difficult to give a hint without completely answering this”.