# Proof verification about the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x$ (L'hopital)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, exponential-function

I know that the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x$ equals $e$. I tried to experiment with ways to prove this because the proof in my textbook was a little too complex for me, and I proved it this way: 
We'll look at the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln((1 + \frac{1}{x})^x)$. Simplifying this (From logarithm properties), we get $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \ln(1 + \frac{1}{x})$.  Now, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x = \infty$ (This is a known limit in my textbook), and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1 + \frac{1}{x}) = (\text{continuity of $\ln$ and $1 + \frac{1}{x}$}) \ln(\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1 + \frac{1}{x}) = \ln(1 + \frac{1}{\infty}) = \ln(1 + 0)= \ln(1) = 0$. Now, we have the indeterminate form $0 \cdot \infty$, so we can calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(1 + \frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}$. This is the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, so we'll use L'hopital's rule: taking the derivative of the numerator and the denominator, we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x}} \cdot \frac{-1}{x^2}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{-1}{x^2 + x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-x^2}{-x^2 - x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-1}{-1 - \frac{1}{x}} = 1$. So $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln((1 + \frac{1}{x})^x) = \text{($\ln$ is continuous)} \ln(\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x) = 1$, and therefore $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x = e$. $\blacksquare$

Does this look correct? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?

Comment: @KentaS Euler's number: $e = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$

Comment: If that's already your definition, then you have nothing to prove since your statement is true by definition

Comment: My textbook defines it as the limit of a sequence, and this is the limit of a function

Comment: If you can show that $(1+1/x)^x$ is increasing in $x$, then you can claim this continuous limit (w.r.t. $x$) is the same as the limit over the sequence in $n$.

Comment: Can you explain this in a little more detail?

Comment: @sag0li in that case I see no mistake in your proof, but i guess the most proper way of proving it would be to show $(1+1/x)^x$ is monotonously growing and $e$ is the smallest upper bound.

Comment: Ahh okay got it. Thanks!

Comment: Since you're looking at different proofs, maybe have a look at this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495797/1070376

Comment: To use L'Hospital you need to differentiate, i.e. to calculate the derivative, which is a limit itself. Most classical textbooks uses the following approach: they first work out some necessary standard limits (in a pre-calculus manner) and then use those to calculate the derivatives of all elementary functions. The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$ is equivalent to your limit in the question. If you use L'Hospital to calculate it you kind of running ahead of the train - it becomes a circular argument. This is why, I guess, they use another method in the book you mentioned.